# Sail own boat from Vancouver to Seattle

Tags: sea-travel, vancouver, seattle

Can you take your own boat from Vancouver to Seattle?

I don't know much about any of this, so any information on type of boat required, if there are specific routes you need to take, and how to travel by boat internationally (if it can be done/how you would go about doing so) is a great help.

Comment: One of the rules for using this site is that you show having done some research. Your question does not show that at all. It is not that hard to do a simple internet search and read a few of the resulting pages.

Comment: IMHO this is too broad and unclear at the same time. Voting to close as such. Please clarify the question, identify the actual problem you have and narrow the scope down to something answerable. So far I am reading the question as "please tell me everything there is to know about international boat travel".

Answer (score 10):

Sure, there is no problem in doing that. You can take any route you like. After you enter US waters, you should endeavour to stop at the nearest port that has US entry facilities. There, you will talk to a US officer who will admit you to the United States (or not, as the case may be, no idea what might happen if you're not admitted at that point).

The US CBP has a web page on this topic titled [What procedures must a small boat follow when entering the United States?](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/226/~/pleasure-boats---procedures-for-entering-the-u.s.) which should provide all the information you need.

Comment: One important detail that's buried a bit in there. The Visa Waiver Program, which normally lets people from 38 countries enter the US without a visa, only applies to people entering on participating signatory carriers, which a private boat is not. US and Canadian citizens (and Canadian permanent residents from VWP countries or Mexican citizens meeting certain requirements as detailed in the link above) are fine, but citizens of other countries will have a problem unless they have a valid visa, even if they wouldn't normally need a visa to visit the US.

Answer (score 3):

Greg Hewgill's answer is excellent in general but in specifics, I'd like to point out this advice from the [Point Roberts Yacht Club](http://pointrobertsyachtclub.com/index.php/reciprocals/for-visitors-to-pryc):

> Point Roberts is an excellent point of entry into US waters from Canada. You may clear customs by stopping at the Customs dock located on starboard as you enter the marina and phoning US Customs for clearance. There is a public phone on the gas dock and one on the main building by the Chandlery.